# IronRuby Get Start

Tags: .net, startup, ironruby

I know the question have answered before but the newsest start up question is on 2009(at least i did not find anything newest). I would like to find an answers for these days. I am .net software engineer and Occasionally i use intellij and old days eclipse for android. So i would like to know besides ubuntu and texteditors, if i should use IronRuby or native with editor or even rubymine or abtana or something else?

I have great problems with rubymine in order to setup all gem and all this stuff to do just a simple debug in windows 7. In ubuntu if i use simple editor everything is ok.

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ironruby you can use IronRuby tools for Visual Studio integrated within VS. If you want an other IDE with Ruby support you may consider NetBeans version 6.x. You can use Ruby, Ironruby or JRuby in Netbeans. Installing Gems can easily be done from Netbeans. Please note that they dropped Ruby support in version 7. Community support is on the way for Ruby but still pending at the moment.